# Colour Factor in QCD Pair Annihilation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, color-charge

My question occurred when I was reading *Introduction to Elementary Particles* by David J. Griffiths. In chapter 8, part 8.5, he is calculating the colour factor of quark-antiquark annihilation.

My question relies in the derivation of three formulas, from (8.82) to (8.84), which read:
$$\mathcal{f}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}} a^{\alpha}_3 a^{\alpha}_4$$
$$|\text{singlet}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}\sum^8_{n=1} |n_1\rangle |n_2\rangle$$
$$a^{\alpha}_3 a^{\alpha}_4= \frac{1}{8}(8)=1$$
I am puzzled by the derivation through these three formulas, does $a^{\alpha}_3$ or $a^{\alpha}_4$ exactly refer to the singlet state? If so, what does the summation over the index $\alpha$ mean? What is the relation between this summation and normalisation of the singlet state?

Comment: You can find what $a^\alpha$ means in Eq. (8.33) and text below.